# Map Fragment shows as visible despite android:visibility="gone"

Tags: android, android-fragments, visibility

I'm working on an alternative simplified layout for an app that is used for smaller screens. This layout should *not* include a map fragment that is used in the larger layout, however, I'm supposed to avoid programmatic changes if at all possible. The activity that shows the layout also does stuff with the fragment using its ID, so I can't just delete it. I tried making the fragment invisible, like this:

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone" />
```

But the fragment remains visible. The same happens when I set the visibility to "invisible". The fragment's default position is partially hidden by a view, but when I move the fragment around the layout, it still shows up as visible wherever I put it.

Is there a reason the fragment ignores the visibility parameter? Is there another non-programmatic solution?

Comment: Have you inflated fragment in your activity?  Added or replaced?

Comment: According to usage, the fragment is only used by setRetainInstance and getMap. I'm not 100% on how they work but as far as I can tell there's nothing there that controls view visibility...

Comment: Did you try it programmatically : `setVisibility(View.GONE);` ?

Comment: No, but I have to avoid programmatic changes if possible, especially since I only want it GONE in one version of the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure this would meet your requirement but you can add a dummy layout container above the fragment you want to hide and add that layouts visibility to gone/visible, whichever you want. But again when you want to show the fragment, you should also make the fragments dummy parent layout visibility to visible.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dummyLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone"  >
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, dora's answer works, but I've been advised to use FrameLayout instead of LinearLayout, it's simpler and intended for use with a single View inside:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/dummyLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" >
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

There's another way that works - changing the width and height of the fragment to 0dp, but this is considered a hack and generally less correct solution.